# A little doubt algebra of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was studying algebra of sets and I found a problem that I could not do. I'm almost sure it's very simple, but I can not see it. It is about demonstrating that $A=(A\cap B^C)\cup (A\cap B)$.

I get that: $(A\cap B^C)\cup (A\cap B)=(A\cup A)\cap (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup B^C)\cap (B\cup B^C)$.

I know that $(A\cup A)=A$ and $(B\cup B^C)=U$, but I am not able to finish the demonstration.

Comment: You're off to a good start. Here's a hint: $A \cap (A \cup B) = A$

Comment: Maybe if you think what these mean.  $A\cap B^c$ means "everything in A that is not in B".  And $A\cap B$ means "everything in A that is in B".  And $(A\cap B^c)\cup (A\cap B)$ means "everything that is in A that is not in B combined with everything in A that is in B".  Is it clear why that will be $A$.

Comment: I can see it, but there is no formal way to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

$(A\cap B^C)\cup (A\cap B)=A\cap(B^C\cup B)=A\cap I=A$

Answer (score 0):

Take a set $A\subset X.$

> Then for any set $B\subset X,$ $A$ is same as part of $A$ in $B$ "union" the part of $A$ not in $B.$

To prove this rigorously, note that $$(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^C)=A\cap(B\cup B^C)=A\cap X.$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice $X \cap U = X$ for any $X$ so you have

$(A\cap B^C)\cup (A\cap B)=(A\cup A)\cap (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup B^C)\cap (B\cup B^C) =$

$A \cap (A\cup B) \cap (A\cup B^c)\cap U=$

$A \cap (A\cup B) \cap (A\cup B^c)$

Now notice that $X\cap (X\cup D) = X$ for any $X$ and any $D$.

So $A \cap (A\cup B) = A$.

And $A \cap (A\cup B^c) = A$.

so you get $A$.

...

But it may be a little more straightforward to simply do:

$(A\cap C)\cup (A \cap D) = A\cap (C \cup D)$ and if $C = B$ and $D = B^c$ that is

$A \cap (B \cup B^c) = A \cap U = A$.